# Microsoft Graph Api Beta DriveItem extractSensitivityLabel returns 403 Forbidden

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, http-status-code-403

We are having a problem with a feature available in the beta version of Graph. We are using this endpoint to extract sensitivity labels from drive item:

POST [https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}/extractSensitivityLabels](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/drives/%7Bdrive-id%7D/items/%7Bitem-id%7D/extractSensitivityLabels)

According to the documentation, we need Files.Read.All, Files.ReadWrite.All, Sites.Read.All or Sites.ReadWrite.All permissions to access this endpoint:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-extractsensitivitylabels?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#permissions

Deserialized token we used for authentication:

```
{
  "aud": "https://graph.microsoft.com",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/xxx/",
  "iat": 1655160900,
  "nbf": 1655160900,
  "exp": 1655247600,
  "aio": "xxx",
  "app_displayname": "xxx",
  "appid": "xxx",
  "appidacr": "2",
  "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/xxx/",
  "idtyp": "app",
  "oid": "xxx",
  "rh": "xxx",
  "roles": [
    "Sites.Manage.All",
    "Sites.ReadWrite.All",
    "Files.ReadWrite.All"
  ],
  "sub": "xxx",
  "tenant_region_scope": "EU",
  "tid": "xxx",
  "uti": "xxx",
  "ver": "1.0",
  "wids": [
    "xxx"
  ],
  "xms_tcdt": "1509395911"
}
```

However, we receive a 403 response with the content:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "accessDenied",
        "message": "Cannot call this API using the current App Id.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2022-06-14T08:00:52",
            "request-id": "xxx",
            "client-request-id": "xxx"
        }
    }
}
```

We have tested other graph beta endpoints and had no problems with them. What could be causing this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that currently this only work with Delegated permissions.
I did not find any trace in the docs if there are some pre-allowed appIds that would be allowed to call this API in Application context.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are calling a particular drive's item and this looks like you don't have access for that particular file drive/item , we can suggest you to please check if are able to access particular drive and items which you want to add extract sensitivity labels ,by calling Get API .

GET /drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}

Thanks

Comment: There seems to be an issue with accessing only this particular endpoint. The GET /drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id} command you provided works fine, as do others such as GET /drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}/content. I thought this might be an issue with the app not supporting graph beta functionality, but I tested it on another beta endpoint (GET /drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}/getActivitiesByInterval) and there is no issue with it.